# How to read nested Json lists using Python?

Tags: python, json, websocket

How can I get all  the `accountNumber`, `name` and `phoneNumber` to be printed separately in Json Response using Python

```
[{
    "msg": "result",
    "id": "testdata",
    "result": [{
        "accountNumber": "123456",
        "name": "CHRISfarmece",
        "phoneNumber": "2333455"
    }, {
        "accountNumber": "553222",
        "name": "name1",
        "phoneNumber": "123456"
    }, {
        "accountNumber": "34566",
        "name": "name2",
        "phoneNumber": "24567"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Its just a list of dict. Assume that it stored in variable named `data`. You can get list of account numbers with: `numbers = [item['accountNumber'] for item in data[0]['result']]`

Comment: can explain briefly.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through the result value (it's a list) and store each value in separeted list like below :

```
data2 = {'accountNumber':[], 'name':[], 'phoneNumber':[]}

for x in data1[0]['result']:
    for key, value in x.items():
        data2[key].append(value)
```